# Flow Update issue

Tags: visual-workflow, automation, process-automation, recordtriggeredflow

I am working on a record triggered flow on the object grant contract.Here grant contract is a child object and the parent is grant.
So my requirement is each time some fields are filled in the grant if I update the grant contract the respective values should be populated into the fields of grant contract.
[image]

[image]

Right now if I just enter the values in the grant ,all the grant contract fields gets populated with these values.How do I restrict in such a way that only if I change a grant contract only then the values in the fields in the grant gets stored into the fields in grant contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the information you have provided I think this is the best course of action.

1. Change the trigger ton when updated only.
2. Use decisions to check if the field needs to be updated.

The more fields you want to replicate from the parent to the child record, the more decisions you will have to add to your flow. this can cause problems later on, because it's not a very performative way to handle large quantities of records.
Also, the maintenance of this will be "complicated" because it will be bigger than what is actually needed for this task.

I would recommend Process Builder, because it has a more friendly way to add conditions to field updates, but I'm kinda conflicted in this matter, because I think an apex trigger would be more efficient, and PBs also have low performance, and it is something that is getting discontinued in a not so far future.

Comment: `but I'm kinda conflicted in this matter` -- one should not be - Process Builder is going away and OP has already initiated work in Flow